# "Enveloped in snowflakes"

Tags: word-meaning

If a building is "*enveloped in snowflakes* from a dark sky," does it mean that:

A/ There is a layer of snow all over the building

B/ There are snowflakes falling all around the building, i.e., it is snowing on it

C/ Although there is not a full layer of snow on the building, we can see snowflakes increasingly sticking on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, *snowflakes* only refer to singular, small pieces of snow, either falling from the sky or distinguishable on a surface (eg. if a single snowflake falls on your jacket). Once they combine into a mass, they're just refered to as *snow*.

As such, a building enveloped in *snowflakes* would most likely refer to it being obscured by falling snow - so that's your meaning b). If you wanted to refer to a building that has a layer of snow over it, you could say it's enveloped in *snow*.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks a lot!